# countdowntimer skipping some milliseconds

Tags: android, timer, countdown

as you can see the last call onTick is happening with 2 seconds, then the next call is nearly 2 seconds later.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

tv = new TextView(this);
this.setContentView(tv);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss:SSS");
formatter.setLenient(false);


newTime = "31.12.2015, 23:59:59:999";

try {
    newDate = formatter.parse(newTime);
    milliseconds = newDate.getTime();


    currentTime = System.nanoTime();

    diff = milliseconds - currentTime;


} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

MyCount counter = new MyCount(milliseconds, 1000);
counter.start();


}
```

CountDownTimer

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        serverUptimeSeconds = (millisUntilFinished - System
                .currentTimeMillis()) / 1000;
        String serverUptimeText = String.format(
                "%d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds",
                serverUptimeSeconds / 86400,
                (serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) / 3600,
                ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60,
                ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60);
        tv.setText(serverUptimeText);
    }
}
```

> Output:

```
10 seconds 
8 seconds 
6 seconds 
4 seconds
```

P.S ~ check video for more info

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7b3hme5ekdqpfi1/79789789.avi?dl=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out :

```
TimerTask runTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code
    });
};

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(runTimerTask, 0, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some mistake on the calculations, it is working for me this way:

[Edited] Just tested this again and its working fine, updating 1 in 1 seconds

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = new TextView(this);
        this.setContentView(tv);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        formatter.setLenient(false);


        String newTime = "31.12.2015, 23:59:59:999";

        long diff = 0;
        try {
            Date newDate = formatter.parse(newTime);
            milliseconds = newDate.getTime();


            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            diff = milliseconds - currentTime;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MyCount counter = new MyCount(diff, 1000);
        counter.start();
    }
```

I saw that you are using nano seconds too, try and use the miliseconds instead.

```
  public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
    private long serverUptimeSeconds;

    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //serverUptimeSeconds = (millisUntilFinished - System
        //        .currentTimeMillis()) / 1000;

        int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60 ;
        int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60)) % 60);
        int hours   = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

        String serverUptimeText = String.format(
                "%d hours %d minutes %d seconds",
                hours,
                minutes,
                seconds);
        tv.setText(serverUptimeText);
    }
}
```

hope it helps ;)

Comment: can you modify in my code .. ur just showing hrs,min,sec

Comment: just did it, hope it helps now ;)

Comment: I need days also.. plz help in that part

Comment: I belive its more or less this you want;
int days   = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60*60)*24) % 7);